# Reusing enum values in separate enum types

Tags: c++, visual-c++, enums

Is there a way to reuse the same enum value in separate types? I'd like to be able to something like the following:

```
enum DeviceState { UNKNOWN, ACTIVE, DISABLED, NOTPRESENT, UNPLUGGED };
enum DeviceType { UNKNOWN, PLAYBACK, RECORDING };

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DeviceState deviceState = DeviceState::UNKNOWN;
    DeviceType deviceType = DeviceType::UNKNOWN;
    return 0;
}
```

This makes sense to me, but not to the C++ compiler- it complains: `error C2365: 'UNKNOWN' : redefinition; previous definition was 'enumerator'` on line 2 of the above. Is there a correct way of doing this, or am I supposed to always use unique enum values? I can't imagine this is always possible to guarantee if I'm including someone else's code.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can, and should, include your enums in a `namespace`:

```
namespace DeviceState
{
    enum DeviceState{ UNKNOWN, ACTIVE, DISABLED, NOTPRESENT, UNPLUGGED };
}
namespace DeviceType
{
    enum DeviceType{ UNKNOWN, PLAYBACK, RECORDING };
}

//...

DeviceType::DeviceType x = DeviceType::UNKNOWN;
```

Comment: Thanks Luchian. Please could you correct my example for me. I'm not sure how to declare a variable using namespaces as you describe above.

Comment: If I declare a variable as `DeviceState deviceState = DeviceState::UNKNOWN;`, I get a compiler error:`'DeviceState' : illegal use of namespace identifier in expression`

Comment: @IAmAI ok then you need to also name the enum.

Comment: Luchian - would you know why this is the way it is (or why the rules the way they are)? It seems silly to me to declare a separate namespace, especially for those who already have a namespace and place the enum within a class. I guess I fail to see what's ambiguous about `DeviceState::UNKNOWN` and `DeviceType::UNKNOWN`.

Comment: @noloader because you can address enum values without the enum qualifier. I.e. you could just write `UNKNOWN`, in which case it'd be ambiguous.

Answer (score 30):

For those using C++11, you may prefer to use:

```
enum class Foo
```

instead of just:

```
enum Foo
```

This provides similar syntax and benefits from as namespaces.  In your case, the syntax would be:

```
enum class DeviceState { UNKNOWN, ACTIVE, DISABLED, NOTPRESENT, UNPLUGGED };
DeviceState deviceState = DeviceState::UNKNOWN;
```

Note that this is strongly typed so you will need to manually cast them to ints (or anything else).

Comment: Thank you, having to use the accepted answer of putting a named enum within a namespace would have been extremely ugly.