# C2365 redefinition previous deifnition was 'enumerator' for external header+lib after VS2019 upgrade

Tags: c++, visual-studio

this is linked to [Redefinition and Enumerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772253/redefinition-and-enumerator/16772314) and [Reusing enum values in separate enum types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411357/reusing-enum-values-in-separate-enum-types) and similar issues.

I have a VS2013 project using a header and lib from an external source which I cannot get a new version from.

When I upgrade to v142/VS2019 and compile I get the error "C2365 'PS_DEFAULT': redefinition; previous definition was 'enumerator'" from the external header.

I cannot find the enum PARA_STATE or PS_DEFAULT anywhere else in the code except in the header.

The header code looks like this:

```
#ifndef GLX_DBMS_H
#define GLX_DBMS_H

...

enum    PARA_STATE                  
{                                   
    PS_NDEF,                        
    PS_DEFAULT,                     
    PS_DEFAULT_LONG,                
    PS_PARAM,                       
    PS_PARAM_LONG,                  
    PS_CONNECTED                    
};

struct Para
{
    DATA_TYPE       paraType;                               
    WORD            paraTypeLength;                         
    char            paraName[SIZEPARANAME];                 
    PARA_STATE      strucType;
}

struct ParaV8
{
    DATA_TYPE       paraType;                             
    WORD            paraTypeLength;                       
    char            paraName[SIZEPARANAME];               
    PARA_STATE      strucType;  
}                          

...

#endif
```

What changed between 2013 and 2019 so this no longer works?

Is there a way to fix this outside of getting a new version from the external?

**UPDATE**

I looked at Messages in Visual studio as suggested and line 3835 in ShObjIdl_core.h has an enum with PS_DEFAULT so that is the cause.

I tried two different "solutions" which both work, but are hacks.

1. I added class to the enum in the windows header line 3828 and it compiled. This is only a local solution though

```
enum class PLACEHOLDER_STATES
```

2. Change the name in my external header file, I think I will only get away with this since the enum is not used in the rest of the code.

```
enum    PARA_STATE                  
{                                   
    PS_NDEF,                        
    PS__DEFAULT
};
```

If I see correctly ShObjIdl_core.h is for COM and the external library uses COM so I am not able to get rid of the dependency.

Any better solutions?

Comment: There is a definition of PS_DEFAULT in one of the Windows system headers (ShObjIdl_core.h) - it's possible that your program is (probably) indirectly including this header (which is for MIDL interface usage, I think). If you know you don't want to use such stuff, you may be able to 'skip' this file - not sure what the best way to go about this is, though?

Comment: Not much we can do without a [mre], these error messages usually give you a location for the conflicting declaration

Comment: On the next line reporting error C2365, there should be a line of information indicating which line in which file has 'PS_DEFAULT' defined. Or we can try to use F12 to find references it is pointing out to below header file with the definition.During compilation, we could use [/showIncludes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/showincludes-list-include-files?view=vs-2019) to check if header files are used indirectly.

Answer (score -1):

In my case
I created `typedef enum { ME1 = 0,ME2 }MyEnum;` in **MDefine.h** header file.
And I was trying to use ME1 in **CtrlBit.h**

And the main problem was

**NOT DOING**   `#pragma once` in **MDefine.h** which has MyEnum.

(yeah!! I was sure that it's not possible that my variables declared in other files..)

---

Also, I include **MDefine.h** in **stdafx.h**

And yeah! My problem was solved))